# Как избавиться от проблем десериализации?

Tags: java, json

Имеем 3 класса

Базовый

```
@JsonTypeName("A")    
public class A {
        ...
}
```

и два дочерних класса с разными enum'ами

```
@JsonTypeName("B")
public class B extends A {
    private Code code;
    public enum Code{
        ...
    }
   ...
}

@JsonTypeName("C")
public class C extends A {
    private Code code;
    public enum Code{
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

При отправки объектов этих классов на слушателе возникает ошибка

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "code"

Как это исправить

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает кода вызова десериализации. Но скорее всего вы вызываете как-то так

```
A a = deserialize(json, A.class);
```

Т.е. вы сами говорите десериализатору создать объект класса `A`. Но у этого класса нет поля  `code`. Решение: проанализировать входящий JSON и определить объект какого именно класса создавать.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, за сериализацию и десериализацию отвечает RabbitMQ

Comment: @mesfex вы так и не показали как вы получаете объект